# Wait until website is loaded fully before downloading Scrapy

Tags: python, download, scrapy, delay, sleep

I am using scrapy to scrape a website and the webpage is not loading fully before downloading the page. How would I set a time.sleep or some sort of delay to ensure the webpage loads fully before begining the download? I am currently using this code:

custom_settings = {
'USER_AGENT': 'User Agent',
'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 10.0,
'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 3,
'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 60,
'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 1.0,
'AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG': False
}

Comment: You will have to use selenium if you want the website to load fully or you can look for an api endpoint to get the data from there

Comment: That's not how Scrapy (or any HTTP client) works. It won't download any furthers resources (eg. XHR requests) unless you request them explicity. Use your browser Dev Tools to inspect which resources you need and yield requests for them.

Comment: Scrapy cannot delay downloads until a specified amount of time passes?